# Do these have any validity in pure math? Axioms of sorts?

Tags: calculus, number-theory

There was a deletion here. Written to give credit to original responders, apologies for my thoughtlessness.  The original post snipped.

(Version 5.1) system of zeros and infinities

The reason for the "system of zeros and 'infinities"  are basically for computaional problems while using a calculator or computer.

If there is an expression g(s) - f(s) = h(s) and h(s=t) = 0 for one or more t then, if this were the intial expression, we may like to keep it intact, for future computations or calculations involving this experssion at s =t. This may result in an aswer that need not be undefined or left as a simple zero.

As for the sign of h(t) I would use a the convetion

(I) s approches t from below even if s is complex, a vector, or multivariable.

As opposed to all that s is (II) s approaches t from below.

As s "gets very close to t" take note of the sign of h(t) and this will be the sign of h(t);

h(t) = +f(t)y_1 or -f(t)y_1 but not both.

As for

g(s) - g(s) = (+/-y_1)g(s)

(+/-y_1 = y_0 - y_0 where y_0 = 1. definitons of this sort will follow.)

is an expression of indeterminate sign.  If during a computation this paticular intermediate result occurs the only reason I can see for saving it is an "equivalent" division by "zero".

Instead a multiplication of, for example,

1/[f(s) - f(s)] = 1 / +/-yf(s) => (+/-y(g(s)) / (+/-y(f(s))) = g(s)/f(s).

I suspect the resulting convetion of sign as shown on the RHS would be correct.

defintions of 0 and oo.

(1) y_0 = 1

(2.1) y_0 - y_0 = +/-(y_1)

(2.2) y_1 - y_1 = +/-(y_2).

......

(2.g) y_{g-1} - y_{g-1} = +/-(y_g).

(3) 1/y_x = oo_x

It should be noted that the "variables" f, g and x, y can be "anything" appropriate in what follows.

(4) y_{f-1} - y_{f-1} = +/-(y_f)

(5) 1 / (+/-(y_f)) = +/-(oo_f)

(6) (y_f)^x = y_{fx}

(7) (y_f)(y_h) = y_{f+h}

(8) y_f / y_h = y_{f-h}

(9) x(y_f) + z(y_f) = (x+z)(y_f)

strange occurances

(10.1) (y_f) ^ (y_h) = y_{f(y_h)} (h > 0 evaluated as) 1.

(10.2) (y_f)^(y_0) = y_{fy_0} (evaluated as) 0.

(10.3) (x(y_0))^(y_f) = x^(y_f)[y_{0[y_f]} = x^(y_f)(y_0) = x^(y_f).

if x is non zero and non "oo" then

(x(y_0))^(y_f)= x^(y_f) (evaluated as) x^(y_f) (evaluated as) 1 if y_f (evaluated as) 0.
(x(y_0))^(y_f)= x^(y_f) (evaluated as) x^(y_f) (evaluated as) oo if y_f (evaluated as) oo.

(11) y_f + y_h (where f =/= h) reamins.

if for example h=0:

(y_f + y_h = y_f + 1 = oo_{-f} + 1 =/= oo_{-f}.

operations (legal and illegal within the following examples)

(12) consider a and b

12.1)

(a - b) = 0 => 
a = b =>
(a - a) = +/-ay_1 => 
(a - b)/a = +/-y_1.

12.2)
if

a =/= b.

then

(a + b) = (a + b) =>

a - a = b - b =>

(a contradiction.)

(a-a)/(b-b) = 1.

(also a contradiction.)

12.3)

a + b + c = a + b + c

a + b = a + b +/-c(y_1)

a similar contradiction as in 12.2)

13.1)

if

a/b = c

a = dy_f

b = ey_f.

then

dy_f / ey_f = c = d /e.

dy_f = ecy_f

d = ec.

13.2)

if

a/b = c

a = dy_f

b = ey_g

f =/= g.

then

c = (d/e)y_{f-g}.

ec/d = y_{f-g} = oo_{g-f}.

this completes my notions (concepts). Other inference can be made if necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry, this really makes no sense at all. What does "place holders until final evaluation of terms" mean? Maybe if you gave examples of how you would use these expressions in practice?

Comment: Say if you had a zero in the form $a-a$ instead of evaluating it zero of dividing by a you would keep it as $b = a-a = \pm{ay_1}$ The trouble would be determining the sign. But may be determined somehow and kept consistent. The same would apply to $c =\frac{1}{a-a} = \pm\frac{y_{-1}}{a}$. Then $bc = \pm{y_1}{y_{-1}}\frac{a}{a} =\pm1$ if you would choose to evaluate. As opposed to it being undefined or getting a error code.

Comment: @SimonRoberts To be honest, I still have no clue about what you're talking about. For example, why would you want $a-a=\pm{ay_1}$? What is $y_1$?

Comment: $\pm{y_1} = (1-1)$ ;see 2)

Comment: What I'm saying there are different types of zeros. Zeros have a tendency to "engulf" the finite e.g $a*0 = 0$. I don't want that. I want to keep $a*0$ intact so that I can use it further down the line. What would you consider $\frac{0*a}{0*a}$ to be where $0$ is this case is a "pure" zero; for lack of a better term. That is in this case $0 = (1-1)$ . I think the expression would evaluate to $\pm{1}$. I don't know how else to explain this at the moment. I think $0/0$ is not necessarily undefined or zero. It can be finite. L'Hopital's rule implies this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you want to use this instead of having to resort to limits I don't think that's a very practical aproach. I don't think you gain anything by avoiding limits and pretends the infinity problem doesn't exists - it will probably show up when you start implementing non-standard analysis anyway. I think using actual infinities is much more error prone for beginners than to do it the old-fashioned way with limits.

Comment: signs can be determined if limits can be incorporated. That is $\lim_{a\to{0}}(\frac{a}{a}) = +1$ not -1.

Comment: I'm not trying to achieve anything except what I may have already achieved. I think this is significant within itself. It is sound within itself. My definition may not match the well established definitions however. Perhaps I shouldn't have called 1/0 infinity (or undefined). Perhaps I should left it as is and called it "d" for example. My intent was not to confuse terms. I used the term infinity as a convenience. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I take that back. I am in fact under the impression that 1/0 is infinity and since there are different types of zeros there are different types of infinities. The values don't approach 0 or infinity they are 0's and infinities. This comment may be found extremely unconventional. But I stand by it for the time being. Beginner or not.

Comment: There are different concepts in math. Math is entirely conceptual. If your concepts are different than these does not invalidate what is here. Just as there are different axioms for different branches of math why can't there be different concepts of zero and infinity? I think I answered my own question. Now to expand and explain thoroughly what I have discovered.

Comment: apologies for major edits to OP well "after the fact" is this apparent in this post and others? AND HOW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is would be a system related to the so-called ["non standard analysis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis). In non-standard analysis, there are infinitesmal numbers that are smaller that any positive real number. Non standard analysis is quite controversial.

Comment: Yes. That does sound controversial. Give me a positive real number I can find one less in value. I think I understand how it relates to what I'm doing however. What I'm doing is strange, non standard, but it is a means to an end; computation. Thanks to all those who have responded so far.

Comment: Not sure how these arrows and check mark work. Am I voting or saying the question has been answered or what?

Comment: Accepting the answer (the "V") is only available for the person who asked the question. It means the answer fits what you expected. Upvoting or Downvoting the answer (upper or lower arrows, respectively) is available for anyone with a sufficient amount of reputation and it means that the person who upvoted or downvoted thinks it is a good or bad answer, respectively.

Comment: I do not accept this answer. Way off base.  Just for the "record".  Am I 'bad' now.